# Meteor: how to override the boilerplate HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, mime-types

In Meteor, scripts are usually included like so:

```
    <script type='text/javascript' ...></script>
```

I understand that this is likely for compatibility reasons, but if I nonetheless wanted to, how would I change it to this:

```
    <script type='application/ecmascript' ...></script>
```

For fun I tried overriding the `boilerplate-generator` package as that provides the "boilerplate" templates which define this behaviour, but that breaks *something* which results in a completely empty (not even any HTML) page:

```
    E20151116-12:21:18.832(10) (webapp_server.js:710) Error running template: Error: Can't call non-function: undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested in trying to figure out how to do the same thing. I'm curious how you went about overriding the boilerplate-generator?

Did you just hack the boilerplate_web.browser.html file in the output tar file?

```
\bundle\programs\server\assets\packages\boilerplate-generator\boilerplate_web.browser.html
```

Or did you edit the one in the .meteor directory?